# Delete and protect workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Need your help badly

I have code that is assigned to "button" to delete the current sheet. Sheet and workbook are password protected. I am able to use the button to delete the sheet but the problem, its not protecting the workbook back. Please suggest.

```
Sub Deletetab()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If MsgBox("Deleting Current Sheet, Data entered on this sheet will be lost", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
           ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
           ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
           Application.DisplayAlerts = True
           Else: Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
    End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193800.aspx

Comment: Try something like this `ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False, Password:="xyz"

Answer (score 0):

You have `ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"` twice in your code.

Please try the modified code below (tested and ran ok on my Excel):

```
Sub Deletetab()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If MsgBox("Deleting Current Sheet, Data entered on this sheet will be lost", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I used ActiveWorkbook.Protect instead of ThisWorkbook and that did the trick. However, if I keep the workbook open for sometime (like 10/15min) it will unlock the password. I know its weird, I am not sure if we have any timeout here or any thing which you can suggest.

Comment: @sady where do you have this code written ? which module ?

Comment: I have it on a module and I have assigned this code to Button on the sheet. As of now code mentioned above is working fine. But my problem now is if I keep the workbook open for sometime (like 10/15min) it will unlock the Workbook Password. I m not sure where am i going wrong

Comment: @sady i'll try to simulate it as well and let you know what i've got

Comment: @sady i have it open for 20 minutes, but the Workbook remains Protected. Are you sure you don't have any code related to Workbook protection anywhere else ?

Comment: I have code on the "this workbook" but thats just to lock. Here it is                         `Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Protect Password:="b2Nice", UserinterfaceOnly:=True
'ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Select
Next
End Sub`